# Structlog different ways to log: msg versus info and debug

Tags: python-3.x, structlog

I see different ways to use [Structlog](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/index.html) and I was wondering what the exact difference is.

Let's say I want to log something using Structlog, you could for example use:

```
logger.msg("My log message")
```

But there are [other ways to log](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/api.html#structlog.PrintLogger.critical), like info, debug (as in the standard Python logging library) which give you the possibility to say something about the importance of a message (which you can filter using loglevel):

```
logger.info("This is an info message") 
logger.debug("This is a debug message")
```

The question is: what is the advantage of using logger.msg as compared to the other ways to log like info and debug? Why would I choose logger.msg?

Answer (score 1):

`msg()` is a remnant from the original generic BoundLogger that tried to have both stdlib and Twisted log methods (`msg()` hailing from the Twisted end).

If you use structlog's internal filtering system via [`structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger()`](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/api.html#structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger), it's [equivalent to the `info` log level](https://github.com/hynek/structlog/blob/930ff0ff61e8e010c98c531ccbacf159572d788b/src/structlog/_log_levels.py#L147).

You can safely ignore it.